# How to get the exact value of css attribute when property is overwritten in css class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume I have `li` such as:

`<li id="1" class="show" style="display: none;">`

and inside the css class I have:

```
.show {
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

I wrote:

```
document.getElementById("1").style.display
```

to get the value of display attribute.

and it returns `"none"`.

However, because of the .css class, it's `display` is `list-item`.
How can I get the correct and applied value of  `display` with js?

Comment: HTML rules apply over CSS rules.

Comment: `!important` get more priority

Comment: Yes, I know. What I'm asking is how can I get `display`: `list-item` by js?

Comment: @mmu36478 my reply was to `ImAtWar`

Comment: @mmu36478 No Jquery solution accepted?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy only if it's impossible with js, so priority is in js

Comment: @mmu36478 oh ok..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) can help https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/16uyukxk/

```
var elem = document.getElementById("li1");
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("display");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just returning style attribute's display property value. Thats you have in your markup.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("1").style.display)
```

```css
.show {
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

```html
<li id="1" class="show" style="display: none;">adsfds</li>
```

But in the browser's output you can see in the inspect element, the `display: list-item !important;` was applied

see the below image

[image]

To get the actual applied style, you can use the `getComputedStyle` as below

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("1");

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem).display)
```

```css
.show {
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

```html
<li id="1" class="show" style="display: none;">adsfds</li>
```

**Note :** You don't need to set the `list-item` to a list item. Its always a list-item by default.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the style that is actually used to render the element, you need [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/getComputedStyle):

```
var display = window.getComputedStyle(element).display
```

By the way, `id` must not be started with number, it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the computed style. See this http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle

```js
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("1"))["display"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Solution:** using **[getComputedStyle](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp)**

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("1");
 alert(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display"));
```

```css
.show {
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

```html
<li id="1" class="show" style="display: none;">
```

**Jquery Solution:** using  **[.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**

```js
alert($('#1').css('display'));
```

```css
.show {
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="1" class="show" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use inline css style, so remove `style="display: none;"` from the html, create a `.hidden { display: none; }` class in your css file and apply hidden or show depending of what you want to do. You will then be able to know if your element is visible or not by checking which CSS class it has.